# How do I append HTML after a form title?

Tags: forms

This is the output I want:

```
<label>Name</label><span>!</span>
```

The only way I can think of is to concatenate my HTML to the form title value

```
'#title' => t('Name') . '<span>!</span>',
```

This kind of works, but is ugly: the output is:

```
<label>Name<span>!</span></label>
```

The #suffix property won't do because it adds my HTML outside of the form element's wrapping div.

Any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't concatenate the result of the `t()` function, it should rather be built up as a single string:

```
'#title' => t('Name <span>!</span>'),
```

Other than that, you're already doing this about the cleanest way possible. Other approaches would involve post-processing the form element(s) to render their title in a different way than standard. I imagine that would end up being more trouble than it's worth unless you wanted to do it globally for every element in every form in the site.

Comment: Won't '<span>!</span>' then be translated?

Comment: @user1919784 Yes it will be translatable - but that's not a problem, there are plenty of translated strings in core that contain HTML markup. If you mean will the word `span` be potentially converted to (e.g.) the German equivalent, then no - string translations operate on the entire string provided so unless you've provided a translation specifically for that exact string, it won't be translated. If you _do_ provide a translation then it would be something like `Nom <span>|</span>` so you would control the HTML markup yourself anyway

Comment: But you should watch out if you have any form validation, because by default it uses the title of the field, so it will then spit out: "Title <span>(?)</span> has an error".